# How to track conversion over GTM of a partner site

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM to implement a GA4 tag into a partner website once a particular event occures. My goal is to track view and also sales of the partnersite where traffic is received from my source.

The problem here is, that the first page view will be working, as the trigger fires upon the variable UTM_source and will place a GA tag on the partner site. This will not work for other pageview there arfter.

Current implementation in GTM:

- Custom Variable
- Custom Trigger
- Custom Tag

[image]

How can I use GTM to create a rule that will fire for all related traffic originating from my utm_source and at best somehow also include the basket value and products.